Neural network for real and imaginary part with shared layers
I am trying building a machine learning model that learns a function f(x)-> y where x is a complex vector (y float). I built a model that splits the data into real and imaginary and then does something with it. It runs on my laptop with python 3.10.12 and tensorflow 2.13, but as I want to switch to a server (tried python 3.11.9 tensorflow 2.17) it raises the error:
Invalid dtype: complex64.
Why does my model in keras does not know dtype complex?
The minimal example:
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models 

#generate random complex valued data with dimension (N,hdim)
N = 1000
hdim = 64
batch_size = 32
epochs = 10
X = np.random.randn(N,hdim) + 1j*np.random.randn(N,hdim)
y = np.random.randn(N,1)

#create a tensorflow dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,y))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(X)).batch(batch_size)


#Some custom layers
class input_manip(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        in_real = tf.math.real(inputs)
        in_imag = tf.math.imag(inputs)
        return in_real, in_imag
    
class output_manip(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, in_real, in_imag):
        output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(in_real) + tf.square(in_imag))
        return output
    

# Define the model
def ftlm_model(hdim):
    # Input layer
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(hdim,), dtype=tf.complex64)

    in_man = input_manip()
    in_real, in_imag = in_man(inputs)
    
    print(in_real.shape, in_real.dtype)
    shared_dense = layers.Dense(hdim, activation='relu')  # Shared dense layer
    dense_real = shared_dense(in_real)  # Dense layer for real part
    dense_imag = shared_dense(in_imag)  # Dense layer for imaginary part
    
    out_man = output_manip()
    output = out_man(dense_real, dense_imag)
    #Output layer combining the real and imaginary parts
    # Define the model
    model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    
    return model

model = ftlm_model(hdim)
#Print a summary of the model
model.summary()

class CustomMSELoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMSELoss, self).__init__()
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        # Custom loss calculation (Weighted Mean Squared Error)
        y_pred = tf.math.real(y_pred)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))
        return loss

custom_loss = CustomMSELoss()
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=epochs)

(The output layer is changed to keep it simple)
I am wondering if it is just random luck that my code works on my machine or is it something with tensorflow 2.17?
If this is not possible - how to share weights between two models if I have to split outside the model?
I tried doing the split outside the model, but then I do not know how share weights for some layers.

Your observation is correct. Since tensorflow 2.16, the complex dtypes are not yet included in supported dtypes.
You can either revert to tf<=2.15 or need to add seperate handling of real and complex values.
The sample code for sharing code is below :
def ftlm_model(hdim):
 # Input layers for real and imaginary parts
 input_real = layers.Input(shape=(hdim,), dtype=tf.float32)
 input_imag = layers.Input(shape=(hdim,), dtype=tf.float32)

 # Shared dense layer for both real and imaginary parts
 shared_dense = layers.Dense(hdim, activation='relu')

 dense_real = shared_dense(input_real)
 dense_imag = shared_dense(input_imag)

 combined = layers.Add()([dense_real, dense_imag])

 output = layers.Dense(1)(combined)

 model = models.Model(inputs=[input_real, input_imag], outputs=output)

 return model

